# Is showing the email address in the forget password process secure?

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, user-experience

I have an asp.net application. In this application , I handle `[Forget password]`. When the user forgets their password I send a password-reset link through email.

Many users complain about forgetting the email address they entered into the application. They want me to show their email address while in the `[Forget password]` section so they can check their target mail.

Is this secure? If not how to secure it?

My team leader advises me to only show the first letter from the email so the user can recognize his email.

Comment: no just a link to reset the password

Comment: @Grumbler He never said that...

Comment: Sorry, this here "when the user forget it i send through the Email" made me believe you sent the Password itself.

Comment: Wait, shouldn't *that be the email you send the reset to???*  If you're letting people give you **a different email address** to send the link to, ...  Aw, who cares.  Just show them a captcha and let them log on as admin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's common practice to send a reset link to the email they registered with.  **However**, when you consider the fact that you have no control over whether (or more probably *how*) that email account has been compromised (folks setup IMAPs to client-side email applications with no future password challenge, kids figure out mom and dad's password, or you name it -- doesn't necessarily have to be some nefarious hacker in Nigeria), then this approach may not seem so secure.  Part of it just depends on what you're protecting.

As for your customers not remembering which email account they used -- that IS a problem -- but not one I'd necessarily try to resolve by showing their email address (or even part of it) on screen.  I'd rather take a different approach altogether, and offer security questions, or even just let them create a new account if need be.

Answer (score 1):

There is no real danger in showing only limited characters of email and you can go ahead with it.

Ideally, I have always created two links. First one is "forgot username" where a user is asked to answer his/her secret questions.

Also, most of the websites (including google, facebook,etc..) are making it sure that you enter an alternative user contact details like secondary email/mobile. This helps in securing the username as well as you can reset the password by identifying your choosen means of communication later.

Answer (score 1):

Very bad idea if you want my advice. If the email is supposed to be something private, don't even show a letter of it because it will be a lot of information for an hacker.

What a lot of website do is that when user enter their email and click submit, you can tell them if the email they entered was in the database. If it is, the email is sent. If it's not in the database, show a message and let them try again. If they have 2 emails, they will quickly find the good one without having to see a part of the email.

Comment: I might also add that showing the first letter will not help in most cases because most of the times, people tend to use their real names for their email and the only thing that change is the domain.

Answer (score 1):

Every info you give to the user you also give to the attacker. If user forgets his password and the email he entered, he can still check all his email accounts, can't he? I wouldn't decrease application security even slightly because of people who can't remember their password and can't remember all the email accounts they have.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest showing only a portion of the email adress. For example, instead of `joe.smith@gmail.com` show:

```
joe.smith@*****
joe.*****@gmail.com
j*****@gmail.com
```

and so on...

Comment: i want some standard way to do that ??
some code please

Comment: I'm not sure of the code you would use in your situation (I can't write code until I see your code). And you would just choose one method. You can easily do string manipulation and masking to do this.